# Do Phantom Liberty quests affect the main Cyberpunk 2077 game?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077, cyberpunk-2077-phantom-liberty

I'm thinking in particular of stuff like the [following](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Vesemir) from *The Witcher 3*:

> In the *Hearts of Stone* expansion, Geralt came across a former lover of Vesemir's. If she is encountered after The Battle of Kaer Morhen, Geralt informs her of Vesemir's death. However, if she is encountered beforehand, there is an extra dialogue option for Geralt to ask Vesemir about her.

Here, *Hearts of Stone* is an expansion, and The Battle of Kaer Morhen is a quest from the base game. Something that happens only during the expansion nonetheless affects the base game.

I'm wondering if there's anything analogous for *Phantom Libert*y (some extra lines of voice are enough), or if the only impact is the extra ending.

Comment: I think you've got things backwards. It's whether you completed the Battle of Kaer Morhen (main game) that affects your interaction with Mignole (expansion), not the other way around. So what exactly is it that you're looking for? Instances where events in the main game affect events in Phantom Liberty (like in your Witcher 3 example), or instances where events in Phantom Liberty affect the main game?

Comment: @Nolonar not exactly, from the quote *there is an extra dialogue option for Geralt to ask Vesemir about her.* Talking to Vesemir is something you already do in the main game, so the expansion adds dialogue options to the main game. I'm not interested in the former of your two examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Answer updated since I've largely finished the game)

There are many places where your progress in the main game (here defined as quests that existed before Phantom Liberty) affect quests in Phantom Liberty. Some examples are:

> In the Phantom Liberty epilogue, what you did with Delamain in [Don't Lose Your Mind](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/Don%27t_Lose_Your_Mind) affects the conversation. The list of netrunners you can call in [Black Steel in the Hour of Chaos](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Steel_In_The_Hour_of_Chaos) varies on your progress in the main game, and whether the people you interacted with survived. There are more options in [Balls to the Wall](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/Balls_to_the_Wall) if you've already met Rogue, River, or Panam and completed their side jobs.

On the other hand I found only a few examples of extra dialogue where Phantom Liberty progress affects the main game.

> If you've already completed [You Know My Name](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/You_Know_My_Name) prior to meeting Lizzy Wizzy in [Violence](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/Violence), you will comment on how you've already met before, and she will say she does not want to publicize her visit to the Black Sapphire. (Conversely, if you've already completed Violence prior to starting You Know My Name, she will give you an iconic headgear in the Black Sapphire.) Aside from that, you can mention Songbird to Alt Cunningham when you meet her in the net, during [We Gotta Live Together](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/We_Gotta_Live_Together).

And of course,

> [Nocturne Op55N1](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/Nocturne_Op55N1) is affected. If you've completed Phantom Liberty and unlocked [Who Wants to Live Forever](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Live_Forever), then you can call Reed from Misty's Esoterica.

A few other things changed. You get extra random encounters, and quite a few gigs now have extra car chase stages. The v2.1 quest [I Really Want to Stay at Your House](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/I_Really_Want_to_Stay_at_Your_House_(quest)) is borderline - you can ask your partner to Dogtown - but they will refuse in a text message. So: aside from the instances above, there are no extra lines of spoken dialogue. Or put differently: if you are aiming to maximize your options, do the main game before Phantom Liberty.*

*Caveat to this: depending on your choices at the end of Phantom Liberty, you can get some unique iconic items that can't be gotten anywhere else. If you do the main game before Phantom Liberty, then there's not much game left to use these items on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In addition to the example that you already mentioned, the [I Really Want to Stay at Your House](https://www.ign.com/wikis/cyberpunk-2077/I_Really_Want_to_Stay_at_Your_House) side job has an additional option if you have access to the Dogtown hideout.

Comment: It doesn't look like this quest was in the original game, though.

Comment: @Allure I guess it depends on how you define "main" or "base" game. This side job was added in patch 2.1, and does not require the DLC to access. If you're not going to count any updates, then I don't see how the answer could be anything but "No"

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.